# frequency of 0s and 1s in a list using pattern matching and recursive functions in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

```
for(int i<0;i<Array.size;i++)
 {
     if(Array[i]==0)
     count0++;
     else if(Array[i]==1)
     count1++;
     else
     System.out.println("not required");
 }
```

This is the code in java. how will this be written in ocaml for lists using pattern matching and recursive function? I am new to OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple fold you don't need to use explicit recursion. Here's a function that maintains the counts:

```
let count (zeroes, ones) = function
| 0 -> (zeroes + 1, ones)
| 1 -> (zeroes, ones + 1)
| _ -> (zeroes, ones)
```

Here's how to apply it to a list:

```
let count_list l = List.fold_left count (0, 0) l
```

(If this is a homework problem, you should try to solve it yourself before asking on SO.)